# Should errors be handled when loading external javascript files dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

To increase web page loading performance I load most of the scripts on the page dinamically (with getScript after document ready). However, I noticed that sometimes scripts fail to load, jQuery's getScript returns with an error.

What should be done in this case? Should the code retry loading the script again assuming it was some temporary problem which prevented the script from loading? Or is it not worth the trouble?

Do you handle dynamic script loading errors on your pages? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Typically if one fails they all fail, unless there's something inherently wrong with a specific script in which case reloading it shouldn't fix it. If you decide to attempt reloading it anyway, make sure you have a limit to the number of times you attempt to reload it.